# Typescript export both class and types

Tags: typescript

So I made my own type def for a module:

```
declare module 'fs-tree-diff' {
  interface FSEntry {
    relativePath: string;
    mode: number;
    size: number;
    mtime: number;
    isDirectory: () => boolean;
  }

  type Operation = 'unlink' | 'create' | 'mkdir' | 'change' | 'rmdir';
  type PatchEntry = [Operation, string, FSEntry];
  type Patch = PatchEntry[];

  type FSEntries = FSEntry[];

  class FSTree {
    constructor (options: {entries: FSEntries, sortAndExpand?: boolean});
    static fromEntries (entries: FSEntries): FSTree;
    static fromPaths (paths: string[]): FSTree;
    addEntries (entries: FSEntries, options: {sortAndExpand: boolean}): void;
    addPath (paths: string[], options: {sortAndExpand: boolean}): void;
    forEach (fn: any, context: any): void;
    calculatePatch (other: FSTree, isEqual?: (a: FSEntry, b: FSEntry) => boolean): Patch;
  }

  export = FSTree;
}
```

So now, I can do that anywhere:

```
import FSTree = require('fs-tree-diff');

const tree = new FSTree({entries: []});
```

and it works! But I would like now to be able to do

```
import FSTree = require('fs-tree-diff');

const tree = new FSTree({entries: []});
let entry: FSTree.FSEntry;
...
```

If I try to add `export` before every `type`  in my module declaration it says at the end on `export = ...` that it can't export with other exports. How can I access my defs from another file?

Answer (score 0):

After checking  `@types/bluebird` with a closer look, I found that:

```
declare module 'fs-tree-diff' {
  namespace FSTree {
    interface FSEntry {
      relativePath: string;
      mode: number;
      size: number;
      mtime: number;
      isDirectory: () => boolean;
    }

    type Operation = 'unlink' | 'create' | 'mkdir' | 'change' | 'rmdir';
    type PatchEntry = [Operation, string, FSEntry];
    type Patch = PatchEntry[];

    type FSEntries = FSEntry[];
  }

  class FSTree {
    constructor (options: {entries: FSTree.FSEntries, sortAndExpand?: boolean});
    static fromEntries (entries: FSTree.FSEntries): FSTree;
    static fromPaths (paths: string[]): FSTree;
    addEntries (entries: FSTree.FSEntries, options: {sortAndExpand: boolean}): void;
    addPath (paths: string[], options: {sortAndExpand: boolean}): void;
    forEach (fn: any, context: any): void;
    calculatePatch (other: FSTree, isEqual?: (a: FSTree.FSEntry, b: FSTree.FSEntry) => boolean): FSTree.Patch;
  }

  export = FSTree;
}
```

was what I was looking for

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go. A lot of DT typings should change to this format. :)

Comment: btw, why they don't use the declare modue part?

Comment: https://github.com/types/* is not `npm install @types/*`. `npm install @types/*` comes from https://github.com/definitelytyped/definitelytyped

Comment: typings in github.com/types is for `typings` and in the future https://github.com/Microsoft/types-publisher/issues/4
These are written in external module format as the module name is already known.  It is a better solution IMO as the module can be mapped to different name, and it support multiple module resolution (nested modules).

Comment: Currently, the typings in DT does not support that, which is quite a problem IMO. However, https://github.com/Microsoft/types-publisher/issues/4 is there for a year and still not resolved. Dealing directly with DT is not easy.

Comment: well I guess with 4k modules tey can't change that now

Comment: Not really, they are independent and can be changed one by one. Also, that's the primary reason for github.com/Microsoft/types-publisher/issues/4 When each typing is managed independently in its own repo, they can be much better utilize git and npm, from dependency management to versioning.