# Best way to export both class and types in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Following this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43726560/typescript-export-both-class-and-types) (~2016) and the **official** documentation of typescript [about `Class` modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-class-d-ts.html)

It is stated that class module declaration file should use `namespace` the following way:

```js
export = MyClass;

declare class MyClass {
    constructor(someParam?: string);

    someProperty: string[];

    myMethod(opts: MyClass.MyClassMethodOptions): number;
}

declare namespace MyClass {
    export interface MyClassMethodOptions {
        width?: number;
        height?: number;
    }
}
```

If I apply this documentation onto my project this my linter screams at me with the `no-namespace` rule ([doc about this rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-namespace.md)):

> ES2015 module syntax is preferred over custom TypeScript modules and namespaces.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-namespace
>   Peek Problem (⌥F8)

and also

> MyClass is already defined

Is this still the preferred way to handle types in Class modules?

**Edit**
It is important that the class remained exported by default

#### Solution

```
import myClass from 'myclass.ts'

export default myClass

export interface myObject {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export the class and interface on their own, without namespace:

```
export interface MyClassMethodOptions {
  width?: number;
  height?: number;
}

export default class MyClass {
  constructor(someParam?: string);

  someProperty: string[];

  myMethod(opts: MyClassMethodOptions): number;
}
```

Comment: Hey. The problem with this solution is that MyClass is not exported by default. Which is the case in my module. So I will have this error: `×
TypeError: myClass is not a constructor

Comment: I updated the code in my comment to export the class as default

Comment: Well, now this is not a type it is the actual Class no?

Comment: which types are you trying to export?

Comment: My bad, this actually works. I imported the class from my class.ts and exported it in this file and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Yuhu! Glad it helped :-)